# getLineCount() on TextView in RecyclerView returning zero

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView and I need to be able to check how many lines there are in a TextView.

I'm using `getLineCount()` to get the number of lines, but when I open my app, it will return zero (even though there are 10+ lines in the TextView).

After some testing, I found out that if I scroll down a few items in the RecyclerView and then scroll back up to the top, it will return the correct number of lines.

Here is the relevant part of my RecyclerView adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Post post = data.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(post.getDescription());

    int linecount = holder.textView.getLineCount();

    Log.d(TAG, "Number of lines is " + linecount);
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on `TextView` to have the callback of `onLayout()` calls:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Post post = data.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(post.getDescription());

    holder.textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            holder.textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            int linecount = holder.textView.getLineCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of lines is " + linecount);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will be fired only for the initial items that are rendered...This wont be fired for the recycled item.. It i better to use on predrawlistener

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to let the `TextView` draw the text before asking how many lines it takes.

Try

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Post post = data.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(post.getDescription());
    holder.textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int linecount = holder.textView.getLineCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of lines is " + linecount);
        }
    });
}
```